# How to read the account balance from Coinbase

Tags: c#, api, coinbase-api

I was able to run the sample projects provided at https://github.com/iYalovoy/demibyte.coinbase.
I am not sure if there is a way to read directly the total account balance, as it is listed under https://www.coinbase.com/dashboard (Total Balance).
The code below is able to retrieve the price (which does not really need to provide the real apiKey and apiSecret), but it gives error 401 (unauthorized) when I try to read the account. The error details are:

```
{"errors":[{"id":"authentication_error","message":"invalid signature"}]}
```

I enabled the "wallet:accounts:read" in my API settings.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using Flurl;
using Flurl.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net;

namespace demibyte.coinbase
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            var host = "https://api.coinbase.com/";
            var apiKey = "my api key";
            var apiSecret = "my api secret";

            var unixTimestamp = (Int32)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract (new DateTime (1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;
            var currency = "AUD";
            var apiVersion = "2016-03-03";  // check value from https://www.coinbase.com/settings/api - it is the build date of Coinbase API (not our Application!) 
            var message = string.Format ("{0}GET/v2/prices/spot?currency={1}", unixTimestamp.ToString (), currency);

            byte[] secretKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (apiSecret);
            HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256 (secretKey);

            hmac.Initialize ();
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (message);
            byte[] rawHmac = hmac.ComputeHash (bytes);
            var signature = rawHmac.ByteArrayToHexString ();

            var price = host
                .AppendPathSegment ("v2/prices/spot")
                .SetQueryParam ("currency", currency)
                .WithHeader ("CB-ACCESS-SIGN", signature)
                .WithHeader ("CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP", unixTimestamp)
                .WithHeader ("CB-ACCESS-KEY", apiKey)
                .WithHeader ("CB-VERSION", apiVersion)
                .GetJsonAsync<dynamic> ()
                .Result;

            Console.WriteLine (price.ToString (Formatting.None));
            Console.WriteLine();

            message = string.Format ("GET/v2/accounts");

            bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (message);
            rawHmac = hmac.ComputeHash (bytes);
            signature = rawHmac.ByteArrayToHexString ();

            var value = host
                .AppendPathSegment ("v2/accounts")
                .SetQueryParam ("currency", currency)
                .WithHeader ("CB-ACCESS-SIGN", signature)
                .WithHeader ("CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP", unixTimestamp)
                .WithHeader ("CB-ACCESS-KEY", apiKey)
                .WithHeader ("CB-VERSION", apiVersion)
                .GetJsonAsync<dynamic> ()
                .Result;

            Console.WriteLine (value.ToString (Formatting.None));

            Console.ReadLine ();
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works fine. I upgraded the API to latest version (date is 2018-01-13). I also deleted all API Keys and I created one for multiple currencies. I was able the see the API Secret only in the beginning, when I created the new key - later it is not shown anymore. I noticed that occasionally, the api indicates that we didn't send the CB-Version and I am not sure why it happens.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using Flurl;
using Flurl.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Linq;

namespace demibyte.coinbase
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            var host = "https://api.coinbase.com/";
            var apiKey = "myApiKey";
            var apiSecret = "myApiSecret";

            var unixTimestamp = (Int32)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract (new DateTime (1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;
            var currency = "AUD";
            var apiVersion = "2018-01-13";  // check value from https://www.coinbase.com/settings/api - it is the build date of Coinbase API (not our Application!) 
            var message = string.Format ("{0}GET/v2/prices", unixTimestamp.ToString ());

            byte[] secretKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (apiSecret);
            HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256 (secretKey);

            hmac.Initialize ();
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (message);
            byte[] rawHmac = hmac.ComputeHash (bytes);
            var signature = rawHmac.ByteArrayToHexString ();

            var jsonCodeBTC = host
                .AppendPathSegment ("v2/prices/BTC-AUD/spot")
                .WithHeader ("CB-VERSION", apiVersion)                                          
                .WithHeader ("CB-ACCESS-SIGN", signature)
                .WithHeader ("CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP", unixTimestamp)
                .WithHeader ("CB-ACCESS-KEY", apiKey)
                .GetJsonAsync<dynamic> ()
                .Result;

            Console.WriteLine (price.ToString (Formatting.None));
            Console.WriteLine();

            message = string.Format ("{0}GET/v2/accounts", unixTimestamp.ToString ());

            bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (message);
            rawHmac = hmac.ComputeHash (bytes);
            signature = rawHmac.ByteArrayToHexString ();

            var jsonCode = host
                .AppendPathSegment ("v2/accounts")
                .WithHeader ("CB-ACCESS-SIGN", signature)
                .WithHeader ("CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP", unixTimestamp)
                .WithHeader ("CB-ACCESS-KEY", apiKey)
                .WithHeader ("CB-VERSION", apiVersion)
                .GetJsonAsync<dynamic> ()
                .Result;

            Console.WriteLine (jsonCode.ToString (Formatting.None));

           dynamic stuff = null;
           try {
               stuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonCode.ToString (Formatting.None));
           }
           catch(Exception) {
               Console.Write("Error deserializing");
           }

           int count = stuff.data.Count;

           for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                string currAmount = stuff.data[i].balance.amount;
                string currCode = stuff.data[i].balance.currency;
                Console.WriteLine(currCode + ": " + currAmount);
           }

           Console.ReadLine ();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no total account value return.

You're accessing the /accounts endpoint, which should be return a paginated list in formatted as a JSON object. You'll have to parse each element to find what you're looking for, do some math, and create a running total.

Regardless, your error is unrelated and has to do with even authenticating to the service.

Comment: Thanks, I will recheck the code. It would be ok to receive a json list. I had more success with a python script, where I was able to read the BTC account (for BTC, I received both a API Key and API Secret before upgrading to the latest API version). I created another key for ETH, but I only got the API Key, without a Secret). If I understand right, they want now the user to create the API secret, based on the unix time.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem. I had two mistakes - the message for the accounts line should be: message = string.Format ("{0}GET/v2/accounts", unixTimestamp.ToString ()); and the .SetQueryParam ("currency", currency) should be removed.